# How to Execute a selected CheckBox in GUI using Java Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, checkbox, execute

I want to execute a selected item in palette GUI using Java NetBeans. I intention to select one or many items first, then execute the button. Here is the code:

```
User user = status.getUser();
Date dated = status.getCreatedAt();
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Connection conne = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                            
    jTextArea1.append("Connecting to database... " + "\n");
    conne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhostuseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");
    jTextArea1.append(status + "\n");
    jTextArea1.append("Inserting records into the table..." + "\n");
    stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set names 'utf8'");
    stmt.execute();
    stmt = conne.prepareStatement("set character set utf8");
    stmt.execute();
    stmt = conne.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO japantweet(ID,date,name,statusLocation,text,source) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    stmt.setInt(1, (int) status.getId());
    stmt.setString(2, getTimeStamp());
    stmt.setString(3, status.getUser().getScreenName());
    stmt.setString(4, user.getLocation());
    stmt.setString(5, status.getText());
    stmt.setString(6, status.getSource());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    jTextArea1.append("this record inserted!" + "\n");
    jTextArea1.append("=======================" + "\n");
} catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is the interface:

[image]

Many thanks for any comment!

Comment: What do you mean by _execute a selected item_ ??

Comment: I mean execute one or many checked items

Comment: The problem here is about _execute_ when you click on `Run` what happens if you choose both `Japan` and `Indonesia` for example ??

Comment: yes that is what I mean. sorry for not clear explanation..

Comment: when you click on `Run` what happens if you choose both `Japan` and `Indonesia` for example ??

Comment: So I can run that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the designer.

1. Select the run button.
2. Right click for popup menu and choose Events -> Action -> ActionPerformed. (or just double click the button).

If you are not using the Designer put this in your constructor()

```
 this.jButton1.addActionListener(this::jButton1ActionPerformed);
```

...

Either way you action performed function would look like this:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                         
    if(this.jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
        // do the thing associated with checkbox1
    }
    if(this.jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
        // do the thing associated with checkbox2
    }
}
```

If both checkboxes are checked it does both things, if only one it will do only the one thing etc.

Comment: It works. yeah this is what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi WillShackleford, I have another question in my posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844564/how-to-import-data-with-getgeolocation-twitter4j-to-mysql-using-java-netbeans if you mind to help me. It is  related question with this post.